# Replace default namespace value from large xml

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

I have a large xml file that has a default namespace value. How can I replace the value without loading the entire file in memory using java?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<customer xmlns="http://www.example.org/package">
    <id>123</id>
</customer>
```

should become

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<customer xmlns="http://www.example.org/another">
    <id>123</id>
</customer>
```

Comment: What have you already tried?

Comment: getting an answer from stackoverflow

Comment: Use a text editor? Or `sed` for stream editing?

Comment: sorry if I'm not clear. I need to do this with java.

Comment: You need to replace the value in the file on the disk? Or do you need it modified in memory for later processing?

Comment: Do you really need to replace the namespace, or do you just need to the Java processing (JAXB?) to process one namespace as if it were a different one?

Comment: input is xml with a namespace and output should be the same xml with a different default namespace value

Answer (score 0):

There's the "hacky" way: stream the file (using a Reader and the "UTF-8" charset) and do a String replacement.

The "real" way is to use SAX or preferably StAX.  You can use an XMLEventReader and XMLEventWriter to stream through the xml and manipulate it without ever loading the whole thing in memory.  when you get the element events with the wrong namespace, create new element events with the right namespace and pass them along to the writer.

Answer (score 0):

There is one way that works fine if your new replacement string is the same size as the previous one (or at least you can add empty spaces if the replacement string is smaller):

Here is a test program:

```
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.RandomAccessFile;

public class Test {

  public static void main( String[] args ) {
    try { 
      // NOTICE THE PACKAGE NAMES HAVE THE SAME SIZES
      String old_string = "xmlns=\"http://www.example.org/package\"";
      String new_string= "xmlns=\"http://www.example.org/another\"";

      RandomAccessFile raf = new RandomAccessFile( "test.xml", "rw" );
      String line;
      int byte_position = 0;
      while ( ( line = raf.readLine() ) != null ) {
        System.out.println( line );
        int index = line.indexOf( old_string );
        if( index !=-1 ) {
          raf.seek( byte_position + index );
          raf.writeBytes( new_string );
          raf.close();
          break;
        }
        // !!! +2 is for end line \n (use +4 if your end of lines is \n\r)
        byte_position += line.length() + 2; 
      }

    }
    catch ( Exception e ) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}
```

What is does is just a Random access directly on the right portion.
I start with a line by line reading but as you are seeking something at the start (second line) it doesn't really matter : there is a break after so you don't read other lines...